# Filtering out peaking distance measurements

Tags: c++, filter, sensors

My C++ program reads an analog ultrasonic sensor.
The data it receives differs from 30 to 500.

The output isn't really stable, because it's ultrasonic on a moving platform.
At the moment I'm averaging the sensor values, which give me a result way off from the actual distance.

The way I calculate this at the moment;

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        distanceTotal += samples[i];
    }

    return distanceTotal / arrayLength;
```

The problem with this method is that when there are peaks, the average shoots up when measuring distances close by.

A example sample array looks like this;

```
{65, 67, 63, 296, 61, 70, 64, 459}
```

It's not sure the first reading is the correct one, for example it could look like this too;

```
{459, 67, 63, 296, 61, 70, 64, 65}
```

Anyone able to get me on track to come up with a clean and efficient solution?
I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: We can't really answer this generically. You need to come up with a processing algorithm that makes sense for your domain.

Comment: You might want to read up on methods of [local regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression), but for removing peaks from signal data specifically there are more specialised algorithms (e.g. median filtering, to keep it simple).

Comment: What do you mean by this? I'd like to make a function to remove the peaks and calculate an average with the measurements that make sense.

Comment: There are numerous filters and smoothing algorithms that can be used, the description of which is far too broad for a Stack Overflow answer. But maybe [LULU smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lulu_smoothing) will work for you? (It's relatively easy to implement.)

Comment: Remove the maximum (and the minimum?), until the values only vary by a defined amount?